# Gremlin querying Edge inVLabel, outVLabel

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I have the following example Edge labeled "posts".  "posts" can can have multiple types of parent Vertice (outVLabel) such as "channel", "publisher", "user", etc.  How do you query for all Edges that have an outVLabel of "channel" without interrogating the label on the out() vertice?  I want an array of "posts" Edges returned.

```
Query:
g.E().hasLabel('posts').has(???, 'channel')

Edge object:
[{
"id": "83c972b0-315d-49fe-a735-882c4dcbdaa2",
"label": "posts",
"type": "edge",
"inVLabel": "article",
"outVLabel": "channel",
"inV": "7410b6c8-ed70-4a00-800c-489d596907da",
"outV": "c8c5f45d-0195-49c5-b7ae-9eda1d441bc9",
"properties": {
  "service": "rss"
 }]
```

Comment: What's wrong with `g.V().hasLabel("channel").outE("posts")`? I don't think a global `g.E()..` scan would be any faster than starting from known vertices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to do:

```
g.E().hasLabel('posts').where(outV().hasLabel('channel'))
```

or if necessary, denormalize and place the outgoing vertex label on the edge as a property, in which case you could then do:

```
g.E().has('posts', 'outVLabel', 'channel')
```